# flattening an rgb image in python

Tags: python, image

I am reading an rgb image as follows

```
  scipy.misc.imread()
```

I want to flatten the array in 1D by picking one element from every channel i.e rgb for pixel 0 and pixel 1 and so on.

Thanks

Comment: Picking rgb for each pixel isn't picking one element from every channel. What do you mean? What have you tried?

Comment: yes, you are right, well, i could not find any pythonic way, i only find stacking which is not what i want, it stacks whole of the channel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doesn't looks like there is `read` in [scipy.misc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/misc.html). Did you mean `imread`? If so it will give you numpy array which have [flatten method](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html)

Example:

```
>>> from scipy.misc import imread
>>> img = imread("test.jpg")
0: array([[[135, 130, 136],
        [139, 134, 140],
        [132, 127, 133],
        ...

>>> img.flatten()
1: array([135, 130, 136, ..., 162, 160, 165], dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: yes i meant imread, thanks for correction, i ll correct it

Comment: What if after getting the flatten RGB , now I want to convert it back to its original form i.e. I want to know what is the reverse of flatten.

Comment: @pranavshukla you need too know the origunal/desired shape and use reshape method:  http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

Comment: How can it be flatten to a list of triplets?

Comment: @MattS check [numpy.reshape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)